# Is Alpine Linux a bad choice for a server?

Tags: linux, alpine

I've been thinking of migrating one of my servers from Ubuntu to Alpine to host my web app. I came to know Alpine because of Docker. Is using Alpine as a server OS safe? Has anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Does the change have the potential to result in loss of revenue for your company due to lack of expertise and/or inability to find consultants willing to support your platform?
- Does Alpine provide must-have features that Ubuntu cannot provide?
- If you're part of a larger team, does the switch have traction with other techs?
- Have you been able to provide your management with a convincing business case?

Add to that: Asking whether a specific operating system is "safe" is a bit pointless. You probably wouldn't want to run any operating system in a production environment without configuring it first. Once a system fulfills your configuration needs it should be "safe" or your configuration definition is bad.